# How can I conditionally render from 2 navbar choices using node, EJS, passport and session?

Tags: express, session, passport.js, navbar, ejs

How can I conditionally render from 2 navbar choices using node, EJS, passport and session?

I would like to conditionally render from 2 navbar choices. I am using EJS, passport and session. I tried a few things but nothing worked. The goal is to render a Login nav bar if the client has not been authenticated or a nav bar with options if the client has been authenticated both nav bars using the same rest of the page. 
I am posting a lot of code here that I wrote following Brad Traversy’s video “Node.js With Passport Authentication | Full Project” (by the way... thanks Brad. Big fan!). I do believe I am close to the solution in the nav-bar file. I just need a bit of help from someone who really knows what he is doing (I don’t). I would really appreciate it if one of you nice guys could take a look at the files below and tell me what I am missing. 
It looks like Tiger Abrodi already asked this same question and it was solved by the Discord team (see [How can i conditionally render the navbar using ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532667/how-can-i-conditionally-render-the-navbar-using-ejs)). However, the answer is not shown. I believe this is a very useful solution that should be posted here for other guys so I promise that your solution will remain posted here for anyone else to see.
Thanks guys! 
My Home Page; you can see I use "include" to call the nav-bar and this works.

```
<!-- Navigation Bar ----------------------------------->
<%- include('assets/nav-bar'); %>

<!--------- Main Body --------->
<div class="mainBodyContainter mBC2">
    <h3>Busca por Marca:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Marca</li>
        <li>Año</li>
        <li>Modelo</li>
        <li>Sub-Modelo</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="button">Buscar</button>
</div>

<!-- Right  ***  Anuncio -->
<%- include ('assets/main-ad') %>

<!----------------- Footings ----------------->     
<%- include ('assets/footings') %>
```

My nav bar; PROBLEM: This decision making is NOT WORKING as it keeps considering user as UNDEFINED. I can verify that the user has been successfully authenticated by checking my dashboard included below.

```
<!-- -- Navigation Bar Decision -->
<% if (typeof user === 'undefined') { %>
<!---- Navigation Bar NON AUTHENTICATED CLIENT -------->
<div id="navBarHTML">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/register">Registrate</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/login">Acceso</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div> 
<% } else { %>
<!---- Navigation Bar AUTHENTICATED CLIENT------------->
<div id="navBarHTML">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notificaciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mis Publicaciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/logout">Salir</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a>Bienvenido <%= name %></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Dashboard

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<br>
<p>Bienvenido <%= name %></p>
<br>
<a href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
```

My index.js; it feeds the user name to my dashboard and it works fine!

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Home page
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home'));


// Dashboard ***PROTECTED FOR NO ACCESS UNLESS LOGGED IN***
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => 
    res.render('dashboard', {
        name: req.user.name
    }));

module.exports = router;
```

My app.js; it works fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const db = mongoose.connection;
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

// Passport config
require('./config/passport') (passport);

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/eyonke_server')
    .then(() => console.log('La base de datos de MongoDB conectó correctamente...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

// Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Express session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`El servidor de eYonke esta corriendo en el puerto numero ${PORT}...`));
```

My passport config; works fine!

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email'}, (email, password, done) => {
            //Match user
            User.findOne({ email: email })
                .then(user => {
                    if(!user) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email no registrado' });
                    }
                    // Match password
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                        if(err) throw err;

                        if(isMatch) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false, { message: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
    );

    // Session
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

auth.js; works fine!

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Necesitas entrar a tu cuenta para accesar este recurso');
        res.redirect('/'); /*if not authenticated, then redirected to home page*/
    }
}
```

My users.js for registering and logging in/out; works fine!

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

//User model
const User = require('../models/User');

//Login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));

//Registration page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

// Register Handle
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];
    //Check for errors
    //Check required fields
    if(!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Por favor llena todos los campos'});
    }
    // Check passwords match
    if(password !== password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Las contraseñas no son iguales'});
    }
    // Check password length
    if(password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'La contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres'});
    }
    if(errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2
        });
    } else {
        // Validation passed
        User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                if(user) {
                    // User exists
                    errors.push({ msg: 'Email ya está registrado en eYonke'});
                    res.render('register', {
                        errors,
                        name,
                        email,
                        password,
                        password2
                    });
                } else {
                    const newUser = new User({
                        name,
                        email,
                        password
                    });
                    // Hash Password
                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>
                        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            // set password to hashed
                            newUser.password = hash;
                            // Save user
                            newUser.save()
                                .then(user => {
                                    req.flash('success_msg', 'Te has registrado exitosamente');
                                    res.redirect('/users/login');
                                })
                                .catch(err => console.log(err));
                        }))

                } 
            });
    }
});

// Login handle
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/', /*'/dashboard',*/
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
      })(req, res, next);
});

// Logout handle
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Tu sessión ha terminado');
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find Tiger A. and he kindly helped me to solve it. The changes I made to my code are as follows:

1.- in app.js I added a global variable as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.locals.user = req.user;
next();
```

});

2.- in my navbar I replace the decision line with the following:

```
<% if (!user) { %>
```

and that did the trick. Now I am able to decide which nav bar to use depending if the user has been authenticated or not.